# datepicker is incorrect in ios9

Tags: swift2, ios9

good morning :)

i have a problem with my datepicker in ios 9 swift 2

this is how my datepicker looks like in ios 8 swift 2 [OK]:
[image]

and this is my datepicker in ios 9 swift 2 [NOT OK]:
[image]

Any ideas how i can solve it?

Comment: Show the code you're using to create and display it

Comment: It really looks like you have another view superimposed on it. Check your storyboard.

Comment: i do not use any code. i only put in on my storyboard und run the simulator

Comment: there is no other view. only a cell and into this cell is the datepicker

Comment: okay i have found my solution. i delete the cell with the datepicker and put the datepicker under the table and all is ok again

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with UILabel and UIDatePicker in same cell.

[image: with issue]

I figure out that setting witch for UIDatePicker based on container view width. Will cause this error, for ex:

- Leading and Tailing to container view
- Equal width as container view

But when you set width as:

- Given width ex. 400
- Equal width as UILable above

[image: without issue]

I hope this will help someone.

PS. I've set gray background for better look. First screen shot shows that UIDatePicker have some issues with rendering. I'm only guessing.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I needed to remove a centreY constraint from the datePicker.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem due to pinning Date Picker to container height & width, solution which worked for me was to also add constraint for width and & height from storyboard auto layout as below -

[image]

---

AppsWise

Comment: a) Please avoid answers that rely on external links; SO aims to be a reference site, independent of links that may not be there in the future. b) Please don't abuse SO as a way to drive traffic to your personal blog. State your affiliations and answer the question directly or not at all.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upload image into answer. Just wanted to help and thats why kept the link there. Nonetheless removed the link to tutorial. Only the image link with hope that it will help.

Comment: Fair enough, downvote withdrawn. Would be great if you could add more of an explanation of how the OP can solve their problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for this, it solved it for me. In my case I did everything the same as you but didn't need the height constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and was able to resolve it by adding datepicker using this code:

```
UIDatePicker* picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 162)];
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue while working with a picker within another cell.

**Simply adding constraints worked like a charm for me.**

Why i need to add constraints to a picker in swift 2 i still don't know.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when adding a UIDatePicker programmatically into a complex UIView heirarchy. I just ended up using brute force, like so:

```
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.setDate(NSDate(), animated: false)
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date 

    var tempFrame = datePicker.frame
    let originalDatePickerWidth = tempFrame.size.width
    if originalDatePickerWidth != self.view.bounds.width
    {
        tempFrame.size.width = self.view.bounds.width
        tempFrame.size.height *= (self.view.bounds.width / originalDatePickerWidth)
        datePicker.frame = tempFrame
    }
```