# How to autolayout UIDatePicker in Swift2?

Tags: swift2, uidatepicker, ios-autolayout

I have no problem doing autolayout on buttons and labels, but I am having a hard time doing autolayout with the UIDatePicker.

Comment: What is the problem you faced?

Comment: check the answers in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769479/datepicker-is-incorrect-in-ios9

Comment: my problem is that in landscape mode the date picker doesn't fit to the screen. This link shows how to do it in objective C, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331752/iphone-uidatepicker-in-landscape-mode. Could someone translate this code to swift2 code for me please?

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() {     super.viewDidLoad()     for subview: UIView in datePicker.subviews {         subview.frame = datePicker.bounds     } }`    [Converter](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code)

Comment: I used that code and I'm having the same problem in landscape view the date picker doesn't take up the whole screen